# Mock a response in Python

Tags: python, mocking

I have two classes: RuleService and RuleRepository

In RuleService I get instance of RuleRepository.

```
from domain.rule.rule_repository_mysql import get_rule_repository_mysql_instance

class RuleService:
    _instance = None
    rule_repository = get_rule_repository_mysql_instance()
    def get_rule_by_id(self, rule_id):
    
        rule = self.rule_repository.get_rule_by_id(rule_id)
    
        return rule.parameters
```

I don't know how to mock results of following call or mock all rule object

```
self.rule_repository.get_rule_by_id(rule_id)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create another, "mocked" module of the `get_rule_repository_mysql_instance`. For example `get_rule_repository_mysql_instance_mocked` and in there implement all the functions you need to be mocked for your tests. Then, instead of importing the original module you can import

```
from domain.rule.rule_repository_mysql import (
    get_rule_repository_mysql_instance_mocked
) as get_rule_repository_mysql_instance
```

You can do this under a condition like `if settings.get('use_mock', False):...`.

If this is purely for testing, I'd recommend checking out unittest.mock implementation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html